# Getpivotdata Pivot location based on a value in another cell.

Tags: dynamic, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

GETPIVOTDATA("Data",{Dynamic reference to another sheet},"Field","Item")

I'm trying to get my formula to be super dynamic. I have 5 - 10 different worksheets with pivot tables on them. I have the rest of the formulas setup to get their "FIELD" and "ITEM" off of a small table of data that can change. I have tried named ranges but again cannot get it to work. The only thing in the getpivot i cannot make dynamic is the location of the pivot table. I was shown the CHOOSE(1,"STRINGS") function, but I do not know how many pivots there will be. I've used the INDIRECT() with vlookups. I'm fresh out of ideas any help welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a named range to refer to the pivot table should work. However, make sure the named range only refers to a single cell within the pivot table. If it refers to a range, or the whole table it will not work.

**EDIT**
If you want to pull the pivottable from another cell, you'll need to use the INDIRECT function

```
    =GETPIVOTDATA("Amount",INDIRECT($Q$2),"Name","Jack","Month","Feb")
```

Cell $Q$2 can contain either a named range referring to the pivot table or a cell reference. In either event, you will also need to specify the worksheet if you're working across multiple sheets. eg, $Q$2 could contain

```
    Pivots!$A$1
```

Comment: I've tried to name range A1 of the pivot with no success already. Basiclly I want a drop down of names or pivots to be used.